# Find a IR transmitter device

Tags: linux, drivers, hardware, serial-port, remote-control

I would like to use the IR transmitter included in a [cubox](http://solid-run.com/freescale-imx6-family/cubox-i/cubox-i-specifications/). 
I did not found any documentation to use it, so I would want to learn how to communicate with periphericals on linux.

Commands like `lshw`,`lspci` did not gave me any information, I think I would have to make it recognizable by the kernel in adding a module, but firstly, my guess is that there is somewhere a way to identify the periphiphical.

Here is the outpout of the command `dmesg | grep tty`

```
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rootwait rw console=tty1 console=ttymxc0,115200 consoleblank=0 video=mxcfb0:dev=hdmi,1280x720M@60,if=RGB24,bpp=16 dmfc=3 ahci_imx.hotplug=1 pci=nomsi loop.max_part=15
[    0.000952] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.486266] 2020000.serial: ttymxc0 at MMIO 0x2020000 (irq = 58, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX
[    1.427117] console [ttymxc0] enabled
[    1.431600] 21f0000.serial: ttymxc3 at MMIO 0x21f0000 (irq = 61, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX
```

ttymxc0 and ttymxc3 could be the ir receiver and transmitter, but how to be sure, and how communicate with such devices?

I already been able to receive IR signals from the IR receiver with the lirc command `irrecord`, but the irsend command returns the error *hardware does not support sending*

Comment: have you tried `lsusb`?

Comment: no, but no result either

Comment: The device may be connected as a serial device. `dmesg | grep tty` might clarify. All of my previous IR Gear was serial. I'd try installing and reading up on `LIRC`

Comment: irsend returns the error: hardware does not support sending. But I am not sure of my configuration